# JavaFX: Creating a button resets my stage/scene/panes background color

Tags: java, javafx, background

I'm making a Javafx game with a pane to hold my elements. The background color is set to black (instead of the default white) using the `Scene.setFill();` method.

```
public class backgroundColor extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane background = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(background, 800, 600);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        //Button button = new Button("Just a button");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This works fine and the background is displayed as black... However, when I un-comment the button line, the fill color is suddenly displayed as white. Notice that the button is only initialized, it isn't being used, eclipse even gives me the warning that the data field "button" is unused.

Is this a weakness of `Scene.setFill()`? Or is this a unintended feature of creating a controller?

I am working on a game where I switch between different displays by changing the scene's "root" property using `Scene.setRoot()`, and before I created a button the color was fine no matter how many times I set different panes as the scene's new root node. However, after I created the button I discovered that I had to use a significantly more complicated workaround:

```
background.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, null, null)));
```

to fix the issue. Is there a better way to fix the background for the scene, or do I really have to set the background manually for all panes?